# Same Element becomes unclickable during iteration

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, automation

I'm using `Selenium` `Python` to do the same action for different users and the flow is as follows,

1- the webpage show list of user ids
2- I search for 1 user-id (Iteration)
3- I click on the check box next to the user-id
4- I click on done

My issue is with the check box, it is clickable in the first row of iteration but then it becomes unclickable with the next row.

Checkbox Element:

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="ant-checkbox-input" value="" xpath="1">
```

I have also tried `ActionChains` but I got the error: `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the input checkbox might be in disable state or some javascript load is yet to happen before checkbox become availabe.

try this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span[1]/label[1]/span[1]/input[1]"))).click()
```

another problem might be xpath changes depending on user you logged in.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input [@type="checkbox"]'))).click()
```

above code will work only if you have 1 checkbox.

This code will try to click all the check boxes present on page, if this works we could narrow down XPath.

```
els=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input [@type="checkbox"]')
for el in els:
 try:
  el.click()
 except:
  pass
```

Comment: Hi Im already using that but its still not working and there are two checkboxes ( Select All and the user checkbox)

Comment: could you provide web URL, please try second answer. Hope it should select first available checkbox

Comment: I have added to the post

Comment: Your Second answer gave error other elements would receive the click

Comment: could you run this tell me the result  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath['//input [@type="checkbox"]']))

Comment: print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//input [@type="checkbox"]')))

The result is 3

Comment: you see 2 checkbox but there are 3. added new code to answer try that and share results.

Comment: It actually clicks all check boxes

1- Click on Select All checkbox
2- Click on the User check box which unselects the user